# Should I add "Possible duplicate" text to a question which is not closed as duplicate (yet)?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Can I add "Possible duplicate" text to a question which is not closed as duplicate (yet), or should I wait until it's closed and then edit it?

Also, what happens if I add links to possible duplicates and later the automatic possible duplicates bot finds this questions? Will it add the same links or will it spot that they're already included (even though I don't use the same formatting for the possible duplicates text (e.g `--->`)) and will leave the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should **never** add the "Possible duplicate" note into a question yourself.

The note is placed there automatically by the system when the message is closed through [regular means](https://superuser.com/faq#close) (users voting to close it).

If you see a question that is not closed, but you're certain that it is a duplicate, then feel free to vote to close it. However, this option is only available to you once you reach [3000 reputation](https://superuser.com/privileges/close-questions). Until then, please [flag](https://superuser.com/privileges/flag-posts) these posts for moderator attention, so that we can take care of it :)

Comment: In addition, if you want to help: vote to close if you have the rep, leave a comment pointing to the question if you don't

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, good to know.

Comment: Also, @tempy, you can post the question in the [Super User Vote to Close](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117/super-user-vote-to-close-delete) chat room, where many 3K+ users hover, so it can be decided quickly

Comment: The [_Vote to Close_ chat room has been closed](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6085/vote-to-close-the-vote-to-close-chat-room).