# Vote to Close the Vote to Close chat room

Tags: discussion, chat, vote-to-close

With the new Review System, questions are getting closed/reopened/improved more rapidly then before. Looking at the room activity, it's been 43 days since something was asked in there, other then one user actually using it to inform us of a question to close.

I feel the room should be closed, since users can flag posts with close reasons if they don't have the necessary reputation yet.

Comment: For everyone who's trying to wrap their head around the post title: *Vote to close the "Vote to Close" chatroom*.

Comment: That's so meta...  =)

Comment: @Crontab That was the point :P

Comment: I think this belongs on SuperUser Meta Meta.

Comment: @trpt4him damn, guess I gotta migrate!

Comment: I vote to close "Vote to Close the Vote to Close chat room".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, since it's been frozen at least twice and bumped … several times, farewell Vote to Close room.

> It roomed us all faithfully back in the bad old days when we needed more room. — 
>   *allquixotic*

The Review queue will take care of the close votes, and if there's anything to be discussed, we still have [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) or the [Ask a SU Moderator](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator) room.

Comment: +1 for the rooming room. Spirit of the question title, whee~!